# Memory usage increases over time when writing to a file

Tags: c++, qt

I have a small Qt based C++ program and this program just writes a vector to a file until I click the "STOP" button.

In the Qt designer, I just put a push button, change the text to "STOP" and name the object "button".

The problem is that when I check the memory usage of the program by the watch command in terminal I see that the free memory decreases over time and clicking on the button does not affect it. It only goes to its initial if I close the application.

test.pro :

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2016-10-12T13:56:45
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -pthread

TARGET = Test
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    writer.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    writer.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

mainwindow.h :

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include <writer.h>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_stopButton_clicked();

    void on_startButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    writer *w;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

writer.h :

```
#ifndef WRITER_H
#define WRITER_H

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <vector>

#define COUNTER_FILENAME "data_counter.txt"
#define DATA_PREFIX "data_no"
#define DATA_EXTENSION ".csv"

class writer
{
public:
    // For labeling
    unsigned int label_id;
    bool label;
    // Start writing frame features in a file
    void write();
    // Stop writing
    void stopWriting();
    // Default demo constructor, sets up the frame thread which will process frame data in a seperate thread
    explicit writer();
    // Default demo destructor, flags that the frame thread should stop and waits for the frame thread to join
    ~writer();

protected:
    std::unique_ptr< std::thread > frameThread;
    std::atomic< bool > stopFrameThread;
    std::vector< float > frameFeatures;
    std::string data_filename;
};

#endif // WRITER_H
```

main.cpp :

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp :

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    w(new writer())
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete w;
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_stopButton_clicked()
{
    w->stopWriting();
}

void MainWindow::on_startButton_clicked()
{
    w->write();
}
```

writer.cpp :

```
#include "writer.h"

writer::writer() :
    label_id( 0 ),
    label( false )
{
    stopFrameThread = false;
    // Resize the vector to put all frame features
    frameFeatures.resize( 1743, 0.0 );
}

writer::~writer()
{
    stopWriting();
}

void writer::write()
{
    // Setup the frame thread
    stopFrameThread = false;

    // Create a new thread to retrieve all features of each frame
    frameThread = std::unique_ptr< std::thread >( new std::thread( [ this ](){
        // Read from counter file to get counter value
        std::string counter;
        std::ifstream counter_in (COUNTER_FILENAME);
        if( counter_in.is_open() ){
            std::getline( counter_in, counter );
            counter_in.close();
        }else{
            counter = "0";
        }

        // Convert the counter into an integer
        int c;
        std::stringstream( counter ) >> c;

        // Compute data filename
        data_filename = DATA_PREFIX + counter + "_id" + applicant_id + DATA_EXTENSION;

        std::ofstream data_file( data_filename );

        if( data_file.is_open() ){
            // Start the main processing loop
            while( ! stopFrameThread ){
                for(int index = 0; index < 1743; index++){
                    frameFeatures[ index ] = index;
                }

                for(std::vector< float >::iterator it = frameFeatures.begin(); it != frameFeatures.end(); ++it){
                    data_file << " " + std::to_string( *it );
                }
                data_file << "\n";
            }

            // Close the data file
            data_file.close();

            // Write incremented counter value on counter file
            std::ofstream counter_out (COUNTER_FILENAME);
            if( counter_out.is_open() ){
                counter_out << ++c;
                counter_out.close();
            }else{
                std::cerr << "Unable to write on counter file\n";
            }
        }else{
            std::cerr << "Unable to open the data file\n";
        }
    } ) );
}

void writer::stopWriting()
{
    // Flag that the frame thread should stop
    stopFrameThread = true;

    // Wait for the frame thread to stop
    if( frameThread ){
        if( frameThread->joinable() ){
            frameThread->join();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: *The problem is that when I check the memory usage of the program by the watch command in terminal* -- You shouldn't use OS tools to determine if your C++ program actually leaks memory.  The C++ runtime's heap manager may be holding onto the memory in case further allocations are necessary.  Add a "start" button and see if the memory keeps going up when you write the vector again.  If the memory doesn't go up, then that confirms that the heap manager is working as designed and there is no obvious memory leak.

Comment: Do you mean add a button to start the thread instead of starting it with the constructor ?

Comment: No, what I'm alluding to is to start, stop, and then start again in the same run of your application.  It is the second start that will determine if you're actually leaking memory.  If you see memory start to increase at the same rate as the initial start, then you can probably make the case for a memory leak.  If you don't see such an increase, then it confirms that the heap manager is doing its job.

Comment: I did as you said and when I stop the run the memory usage remains at the same value but when I (re-)start, it continues to increase :( So, it means that I have a memory leak, doesn't it ? Where could it be coming from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is been a while since I fixed the issue but I thought I should write it here in case someone encounters a similar problem.

There was not any bug, nor any memory leak in the code. The program works perfectly. The issue was that the process of creating new vectors was faster than than the one writing to the file.

I solved it by having two separate threads to speed up the process. The first thread would create vectors and store them in a buffer. The second thread would take a vector from that buffer and write it.